# Change LSCOLORS using fish on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, fish

I'm trying to set the colour of dirs in Terminal on the latest version of macOS (12.5) with an M1 using fish.

I've tried both the suggested commands:
`set LSCOLORS XXXX` and `set -Ux LSCOLORS XXXX` with XXXX being the desired colour e.g. G or "dir=1:37".

Both options do change the values in fish_variables (found in the .config/fish dir) but the colours stay the same.

I've looked through the preferences pane for Terminal itself as well as the fish_config but I can't see anything overriding what I'm trying to alter.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `set -U` when exporting env vars. It's likely to cause problems. Just do `set -x` to export an env var. You should be able to confirm it is exported by running `env | grep LS_COLORS`. For example, on my system:

```
> env | grep LS_COLORS
LS_COLORS=di=34:ln=35:so=32:pi=33:ex=31:bd=34;46:cd=34:su=0:sg=0:tw=0:ow=0:
```

If the var is exported and not producing the expected result then the problem has nothing to do with Fish. In particular, note that the macOS `ls` command (the */bin/ls* one) **does not** recognize the `LS_COLORS` env var. That is a GNU Linux extension. I recommend installing the Homebrew package manager and then `brew install coreutils` which will provide `gls` command. You can then create a Fish function that invokes `gls` when you type `ls`.